# Concurrency/Timestamp required for new Entity

Tags: breeze

Trying to save a new Entity with this field

```
[Timestamp]
    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

throws the validation error `Required`. I am not setting any value on TimeStamp before save. Saving an existing item changes the TimeStamp in the DB as expected.

This value is set by the DB itself and as such does not need to be initialized, or am I wrong here?

EDIT:

This works i think because it is nullable

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int? RowVersion { get; set; }
```

A new DB-Entry has null as value. Any change from within my app changes this and adds 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and is now fixed in v 0.76.4.  You should be able to use SQL Server timestamps cleanly now.  ...  Thanks for finding this, Sascha.